# MVC How make a logout button

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

First CSS isnt my strong skill. Im following this example to create my menu bar

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_active

First I try put it on **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xc0jctjt/6/)** but doesnt look the same

I can make the green selected change when user select different button. Can change between Login and Username when user is authenticated.

In my View I change it to something like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Login">Login</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#Logout" style="color: red">Welcome Administrator Logout</a> </li>
</ul>
```

But doesnt stay on same line and doesnt look to good. Any suggestion on how improve my UI? Make it stay on same line or change the approach?

[image]

Current CSS:

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Note that you have `color: white;` (for `li a`) so you cannot see it in the fiddle - change it to something that contrasts with the background

Comment: @StephenMuecke I update the CSS with a darker background. I also remove the `<p>` now show in the same line but everything is red

Comment: Its red because you last link has `style="color: red"`. When you say you want it all on the same line, it is all on the same line (so long as you increase the width of the window)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean I want the `administrator` on white and only `logout` on red. That is why I try with `p` to separated. But I think replacing `logout` with a picture solve that. At least that is what I can solve it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improve the style using a door image.

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="#about">Login 
      <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/25oxgxz.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="#Logout" style="color: red">Welcome Administrator
      <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/157n953.png" border="0"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xc0jctjt/7/)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd updated your jsFiddle

You should separate the Welcome administrator message from the Logout button

Comment: what should I use to separate? I remove the `<p>` and at least show in the same line. But everything is the same red color